# Comparison between Parameters Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, business-intelligence

I'd like to pass the value of a parameter if it contains certain word in the value field and I have this query:

```
="[Orders].[PrevMonth].&["
& switch(
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Enero %","Enero",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Febrero %","Febrero",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Marzo %","Marzo",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Abril %","Abril",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Mayo %","Mayo",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Junio %","Junio",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Julio %","Julio",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Agosto %","Agosto",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Septiembre %","Septiembre",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Octubre %","Octubre",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Noviembre %","Noviembre",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "%Diciembre %","Diciembre")
&" "
& year(now) 
&"]"
```

but seems not to work properly or doesn't pass the correct value, any ideas on how I can solve this?

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The Value expression for the query parameter ‘OrdenesMesFin’ contains an error: The expression referenced a non-existing parameter in the report parameters collection. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)
```

Comment: Is `OrdenesMesFin` exists in Parameters? Make sure it is spelled correctly and also check the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is pointing at an issue with a parameter reference - I would check the OrdenesMes parameter exists. The name is case-sensitive.

After that, to achieve what you want, I would replace each = with Like, and each % with *, e.g.

`Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value Like "*Enero *","Enero",`

Comment: thanks for the answer to my question, but the error keeps on:
    An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The Value expression for the query parameter ‘OrdenesMesFin’ contains an error: The expression referenced a non-existing parameter in the report parameters collection. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Comment: Perhaps you haven't covered all the possible values of Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value in your Switch.  Try adding a final pair of parameters at the end of the Switch e.g. ` , True , "Unknown month"`

Comment: Hi again, I tried changing the sql like this, but keeps saying same mistake. I'm brand new in this.
    ="[Ordenes].[MesFin].&["& switch(
    Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value, True, "All",
    Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value Like "*All*","All",
    Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value Like "*Enero*","Enero"...
    & switch(
    Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value, True, "",
    Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value Like "*All*","",
    Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value Like "*2013*"," 2013",
    Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value Like "*2014*"," 2014")
    &"]"

Comment: You've removed the wildcards from the Like clauses. Why havent you just followed my example? Your also now not following the correct syntax for Switch.

Comment: I followed your example in the following form:
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "*Septiembre *","Septiembre",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "*Octubre *","Octubre",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "*Noviembre *","Noviembre",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value = "*Diciembre *","Diciembre",
Parameters!OrdenesMes.Value, True, "Unknown month")
&" "
& year(now) 
&"]"
I'm not quite sure if you meant that, because the report is still with the same error. Thanks for your patience